# Understanding {0} in C# and how things are referenced

Tags: c#

I am VERY new to C# programming with a light backround in C++ and HTML, so I am pretty much starting from scratch. I was looking though the msdn tutorials, the properties tutorial specfically, and there is only one part so far I do not understand. There is a part in the code goes like this:

```
// person.cs

using System;

class Person
{

private string myName ="N/A";

private int myAge = 0;

// Declare a Name property of type string:
public string Name
{
    get 
    {
       return myName; 
    }
    set 
    {
       myName = value; 
    }
}

// Declare an Age property of type int:
public int Age
{
    get 
    { 
       return myAge; 
    }
    set 
    { 
       myAge = value; 
    }
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return "Name = " + Name + ", Age = " + Age;
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Simple Properties");

    // Create a new Person object:
    Person person = new Person();

    // Print out the name and the age associated with the person:
    Console.WriteLine("Person details - {0}", person);

    // Set some values on the person object:
    person.Name = "Joe";
    person.Age = 99;
    Console.WriteLine("Person details - {0}", person);

    // Increment the Age property:
    person.Age += 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Person details - {0}", person);
}
}
```

and the program's output is this:

```
Simple Properties
Person details - Name = N/A, Age = 0
Person details - Name = Joe, Age = 99
Person details - Name = Joe, Age = 100
```

Now I understand that {0} is effectivly a placeholder that references a part of the code, in this case it is "person", but I do not understand how this part:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Name = " + Name + ", Age = " + Age;
}
```

is listed under "person". I don't see the connection like I do with "name" and "age". Could someone highlight the part of the code that makes the connection and possibly explain it as well if it is not to much to ask? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using string formatting. The `WriteLine` has an overload where the first parameter is a format string, so you are doing the same thing as:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Person details - {0}", person));
```

The `Format` method takes the value parameters and turns them into strings, then inserts them into the format string. The standard method for turning anything into a string is calling the `ToString` method, which every objects has. If you want to specify what something looks like when it is turned into a string, you override the `ToString` method.

So, in the end the code is doing the same as:

```
Console.WriteLine("Person details - " + person.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you, all of the other answers are good, but this was the most helpful to me for visualization purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You're using .Net's string formatting service (the code that allows you to write `{0}`.

.Net will call the `ToString()` method on every object you pass to convert it into a string. (if it's already a string, `string.ToString()` will just return itself)
Since you overrode the `ToString()` method in your class, it gets called by the system.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't just call ToString() on everything, and strings just return itself??? ;-)

Answer (score -1):

This is not strictly an answer to your question - others explained how `ToString()` is involved below. I added it here because you said you were new to C#.

I'd advise not to use the `{0}` way to format your strings - it's a spectacularly slow way of doing things and it's only in C# to appease former C programmers who expect something similar to `printf()`. It's much faster to execute

```
Console.WriteLine ( "Age: " + Age.ToString() );
```

When you use `{0}`, etc., the `Format()` function (and its variants that accept this input style) first has to parse the output to detect the various formatting options and then still concatenate the various strings together.

(In my opinion it's also much harder to read the `{0}` formatting style because if you have 5-6 input parameters in your format string, it's hard to find the matching input parameter in the parameter list that follows the string. This is just personal preference, but here's an example to prove this point):

```
Console.WriteLine ( "Details: 1.Age: {0}\n2.First Name: {1}\n3.Last Name: {2}\n",
    FirstName, LastName, Age );
```

Can you spot the error? This is just with 3 parameters - using 5-6 (as is very common in production code) it's hard to read this kind of formatting. But again, this is personal preference.

Comment: Why did you downvote it? It's correct in every detail. You don't have to agree with it but it's definitely correct.

Comment: At least with string.Format() you can pass in a culture and have that passed through to all the formatting. Plus of course you can use formatting parameters to do fun things with numbers, dates and so on. And of course you don't end up with lots and lots of immutable strings that + after + after + leaves.

Comment: @blowdart Yes, you absolutely do end up with an identical number of immutable strings. `Format()` internally simply parses your input string and then simply calls `.ToString()` on each parameter one by one. Everything you mention can be done with one of the `ToString()` overloads and it'll be simpler because the parsing part doesn't have to be done.

Comment: Actually you're wrong - string.Format uses a stringbuilder behind the scenes.

Comment: @blowdart That doesn't matter, you still need to pass in strings to `StringBuilder`. When you write `{0}`, the matching input parameter is not even known to be of any specific type - it's `object`. Even if you pass that in to a `StringBuilder`, it'll still have to call `ToString()` on it, creating a temporary string instance. You don't actually save anything this way. `String.Concat()` has several overloads that take multiple strings which are much faster. (The compiler calls `String.Concat()` when you use `+` in strings.)

Comment: This is the sort of micro-optimization that we don't need. If you are formatting a very large number of strings, then worrying about whether {0} is faster than concatenation is fine. In this case, it's very likely to be irrelevant. And if it's irrelevant, I'd opt for going for the more readable code. Note that using {0} is not necessarily more readable, but often is.